# I have zopepy in my buildout recipe, but it is not created

Tags: zope, buildout

I like to have tests in my Zope product; currently I have doctests in some files, but to use them (as far as the module uses Zope functionality), I currently need to copy them into a sandbox directory and transform some imports.  I suppose `zopepy` would help me to run my tests directly where they are, but I currently don't have it.

In my buildout script, I have:

```
[buildout]
extends = versions.cfg
extensions =
    lovely.buildouthttp
    mr.developer

package-name =

parts +=
    instance
    test
    backup
    paths
    i18nduder
    zopepy

[zopepy]
recipe=zc.recipe.egg
eggs = ${instance:eggs}
interpreter = zopepy
# extra-paths = ${instance:extra-paths}
scripts =
```

(I hope I didn't cut anything important; of course it is much longer.  There are no more occurrences of `zopepy`.)

When I run buildout, everything looks fine:

```
...
Generated script '/var/zope-instance/theinstance/bin/i18ndude'.
Generated script '/var/zope-instance/theinstance/bin/duder'.
Installing zopepy.
Updating backup.
```

But afterwards I simply **don't have** a `zopepy` in my `bin/` directory, and nowhere else along the `PATH` of my `virtualenv`.

What the heck is happening here? How can I debug this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my. I found the answer. Looks quite trivial for someone familiar with buildout. I simply needed to change the `scripts` assignment to

```
scripts = zopepy
```

(I have no idea why this was changed.)
After re-running buildout I had my `zopepy` script.
It seems the interpreter doesn't exist unless it is used for the script.